# Ayuda exportar a excel - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estuve intentando exportar los datos de unos formularios con laravel pero no aparece la descarga solo se actualiza la pagina, estoy usando maatwebsite/excel para realizar las exportaciones mi db solo cuenta con una tabla 'formulario' Adjunto mi código para que me puedan ayudar:
cuento con un modelo llamado Formulario.

Mi controlador

```
public function getExport(){
    $formulario=Formulario::all();
    Excel::create('Formulario',function($excel) use($formulario){
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1',function($sheet) use($formulario){
            $sheet->fromArray($formulario);
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

}

Este es mi boton en el index.blade

```
<a href="{{URL::to('getExport')}}"><button style="margin: 5px" class ="btn btn-success">Exportar en excel</button></a>
```

Aqui mi ruta

```
Route::get('/getExport','FormularioController@getExport');
```

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], entonces eso es lo que has tratado ahora por favor edita y coloca que error o fallo tienes

Comment: Una sugerencia: mejor usa spout php para exportar tus tablas, es más eficiente y no es necesario configurar muchas cosas para hacerlo fuhcionar en laravel, más que agregarlo al composer y actualizar.